# Cannot convert value of type '[HKQuantityType?]' to specified type 'Set'

Tags: ios, swift, set

Getting this error when updating to Swift 2

> Cannot convert value of type '[HKQuantityType?]' to specified type 'Set'

```
private let stepsCountIdentifier = HKQuantityType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount)


func authorizeHealthKit(completion: ((success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void)) {
    let healthKitTypesToRead: Set = [stepsCountIdentifier]

    if !HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() {
        completion(success: false, error: NSError(domain: "steps", code: -1, userInfo: nil))
        return
    }

    healthKitStore.requestAuthorizationToShareTypes(Set(), readTypes: healthKitTypesToRead) { (success, error) -> Void in
        completion(success: success, error: error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to unwrap the optional `stepCountIdentifier` before you initialize your `healthKitTypesToRead` Set.

```
if let stepsCountIdentifierUnwrapped = stepsCountIdentifier {
    let healthKitTypesToRead: Set = [stepsCountIdentifierUnwrapped]
}
```